# Would WHERE col1 and ORDER BY col2 use a composite key on (col1,col2)?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table (potentially huge, with hundreds of millions of records in the future) on which I would execute the following query very often:

```
select *
from table1
where col1 = [some number]
order by col2
```

Obviously having an index on "col1" would make it run fast. col1 is not unique, so many rows (2000+ I expect) would be returned.

Does it make sense to create an index on (col1, col2)? Would MySQL use it for this query?

Also, if I just query without "order by" part, would this index be used as well for the "where" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Yes, it will help, mysql will use composite index with first part on WHERE and second part on ORDER BY. You can read  about ORDER BY optimization here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: The second example on that page is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.